# jaxb sourcecode generated from xsd in java 11 failed to find java.lang

Tags: maven-jaxb2-plugin, java-11

I have started java 11 migration but i am not able to migrate jaxb. Sources are generated, however compilation fails as java lang classes such as String are missing. Is there any tutorial explaining how to use jaxb with jdk 11? I follow some tutorials with no success. Thanks

I've already added to my pom jaxb dependencies and maven-jaxb2 plugin

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0-b180830.0359</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0-b180830.0438</version>
            </dependency>
..
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-jaxb2-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generate</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
                        <schemas>
                            <schema>
                                <fileset>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**/*.xsd</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </fileset>
                            </schema>
                        </schemas>
                        <strict>false</strict>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

Objects and types in java.lang are not found

```
AbstractSoapOverRestConnectorConfiguration.java (at line 38)
        return new WorldSpanSoapConnector(restConnector, httpSettings.getEndpoint(), soapAction);
                                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^
The method getEndpoint() from the type BaseHttpSettings refers to the missing type String


AbstractSoapOverRestConnectorConfiguration.java (at line 39)
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
NoSuchAlgorithmException cannot be resolved to a type
```